# Trouble with using header and source files

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn how to use header/source files in c++ programs, but I have been unable to get even a very basic program to compile properly. When I try to compile, I get errors such as "expected unqualified-id" or "use of undeclared identifier"

This is all I have in my header file (project5functions.h):

```
#ifndef project5functions_h
    #define project5functions_h

    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

            std::int testing123(std::int a);
#endif
```

The associated project5functions.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "project5functions.h"

using namespace std;
int testing123(int a) {
            return a + 4;
    }
```

And my main c++ file that I try to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
    #include "project5functions.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main () {
            cout << testing123(7) << endl;

            return 0;
    }
```

I honestly have no clue what could be causing the problem since most of the answers I found online had to do with syntax of declaring classes, which is above my level. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is a screenshot of the compilation

[image: errors]

As a side note, I was able to get it working by simply pasting the entire from the .cpp file to the .h file and adding `using namespace std`, but I have heard that this isn't the recommended method. Why is that?

Comment: You don't need `std::int`, `int` is enough in C++.

Comment: @LeFlou As proven `std::int` is even blatantly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the std namespace (`std::`) for integers in your header file. So in project5functions.h, changing

```
std::int testing123(std::int a);
```

to

```
int testing123(int a);
```

should to the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Type int is not part of the std namespace, don't use std::int, just use int.

To answer your second question, using namespace std will flood your scope with the methods inside the std namespace. Namespaces help reduce conflicts with other namespaces.

Comment: In translation units `using namespace std;` may be considered OK, but depends though.

Comment: It may be okay, but there's no reason to. They're a part of the language.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense